# Калькулятор на Android

Tags: android

Люди подскажите, пожалуйста, исходный код калькулятора под Android. А то не получается сделать сложение, вычитание, умножение и деление. Может есть у кого. Заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено.**

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public EditText edittext;
    public String str1="";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        final Button but_1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);

        but_1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.but1:str1+="1";
            edittext.setText(str1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Эта обычная кнопка, выводящая в поле ввода цифру 1. А как сделать кнопку сложение или вычитание?

Comment: Покажите свой код, и я скажу, где ошибка.

Comment: Код в студию)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужен научный калькулятор, то есть готовый код: [Scientific Calculator for Android](http://code.google.com/p/scientific-calculator-for-android/), который вы можете изучать и модифицировать под себя.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте алгоритм Дейкстры: [алгоритм сортировочной станции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Вот [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154739/android-help-with-calculator-logic) можете взять нужный код.